# ssh -vT git@github.com Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, permissions, git

Don't know why but my dev environment is broken.
I'm unable to execute npm install properly because of issues with SSH connection

For some reason my ssh connections are not working. Please help!

I obfuscated console outputs with myUsername and my SHA256

When I try:
ssh -vT git@github.com (from git bash)

This is the result:

```
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh_0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa     SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

ssh -vT git@github.com (from windows console)

This is the result:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh_0.7.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config

```
# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
```

$ ssh-add -l result

```
2048 <my SHA256>  /c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

Comment: How did you get `/c/Users/<myUsername>/.ssh/id_rsa`into the config?

Comment: I run this command trying to fix my env today ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 0):

Git Upgrade helped. I apologize for an unnecessary question.